# "I am happy (that or since) you are back"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

The question is:

> I am happy .... you are back.
> a) while
> b) that
> c) however
> d) since

I think both b and d are correct

I asked some of my friends and they told to choose option b but I think option d works .. since related to reason

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct, but I think answer b) sounds more natural -- "I'm happy *that* you are back". I've never heard someone say "I'm happy since you are back." But I have heard "I'm happy since you *came* back." But since that option isn't there, I would definitely go with answer b).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct. Both work here - *"since"* indicating a reason, and *"that - meaning: I am happy to have you here again"* connecting the two clauses.

It could be a poorly designed question.

Further, I think "while" can work there but the second part of the sentence should be "you are here."

Comment: So for this question what should I choose ? I an still confused about it

Comment: If you think both are correct, then choose both as I mentioned in my answer.